# Objective-C: Date picker and level indicator

Tags: objective-c

I'm using an NSDatePicker and NSLevelIndicator to try and set/display certain values of an object.  I don't want to use bindings.  My first thought would be to try and set a delegate of the date picker/level indicator to be my controller class so that I can be notified when either of those is changed.  However, NSDatePicker and NSLevelIndicator don't have a delegate (at least, none that I can see in interface builder).  How then do I keep track of when these things are changed?

Comment: I can get it to work using IBActions, I guess I was just curious as to why there weren't delegate methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSControl and its subclasses use the target / action mechanism to alert you when their value changes. Some delegate protocols work in a similar manner, but in general delegates are used to modify the behavior of an object, while target / action alerts your controller of a change in a UI control.